# getView in ArrayAdapter is not being called

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I've made my own ArrayAdapter but I'm having issues with the getView method - it's never being called. My Logcat is only showing the log from the constructor and never from getView. I've tried changing to a BaseAdapter and tried overriding getCount but with no luck, getView won't get called. I've ensured that the list that's passed in is not empty, but still no luck. This is my code:

```
public class ProgramSelectionSchoolAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private ArrayList<String> schools;
private Activity context;

private static final String TAG = "ProgSelSchoolAdapter";

public ProgramSelectionSchoolAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> schools) {
    super(context, R.layout.spinner_program_selection_row, schools);
    this.schools = schools;
    this.context = context;

    Log.v(TAG, "ProgramSelectionSchoolAdapter was created");
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;

    Log.v(TAG, "getView was called");

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (rowView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        // Inflate the row layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_program_selection_row, parent, false);

        // Use of view holder to save performance
        holder.spinnerItem = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvSpinnerItem);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    // Set the text for the view holder
    String school = schools.get(position);
    holder.spinnerItem.setText(school);

    Log.v(TAG, school + " added to spinnerItem");

    return rowView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView spinnerItem;
}
```

}

And here is how I use the adapter:

```
private void setUpSpinner() {

    // Construct a list to be used for storing unique school values for the adapter
    schools = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Query for all organizers
    ParseQuery<Organizer> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Organizer.class);
    query.whereEqualTo(COLUMN_APP, APP_NAME);
    query.orderByAscending(COLUMN_SCHOOL);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Organizer>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<Organizer> organizers, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null) {
                // All organizers for the chosen app was received successfully

                Log.v(TAG, "Organizers received successfully");

                // Go through all organizers and look for unique school values
                for (Organizer organizer : organizers) {

                    String school = organizer.getSchool();
                    if(!schools.contains(school)) {
                        // Add the unique school to the ArrayList
                        schools.add(school);

                        Log.v(TAG, school + " added to list");
                    }

                }

                // Create the adapter for the schools
                adapterSchools = new ProgramSelectionSchoolAdapter(ProgramSelection.this, schools);
            } else {
                // Something went wrong
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Create spinner and set adapter
    spinnerPrograms = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPrograms);
    spinnerPrograms.setAdapter(adapterSchools);

}
```

I'm using a similar adapter for another activity in the application, and that one works just fine. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are using the adapter?

Comment: It's in the edit now :)

Comment: your adapter is null, because the query is done, as the name suggests, in the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `spinnerPrograms.setAdapter(adapterSchools);` while `adapterSchools` is null. Although it looks like you are setting the variable to a new ProgramSelectionSchoolAdapter, that code is not actually called until after the background task completes. Try calling setAdapter in the `done` method.